# How to classifies the distinct "plasma" phases of matter?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, phase-transition, plasma-physics

> 1. How to classifies the distinct "plasma" phases of matter?

and

> 2. What theory classifies the distinct "plasma" phases of matter?

According to Wikipedia:
Plasma (from Greek πλάσμα, "anything formed") is one of the four fundamental states of matter, the others being **(i) solid, (ii) liquid, and (iii) gas. A (iv) plasma** has properties unlike those of the other states.

```
 For (i) solid, (ii) liquid, and (iii) gas:
```

We know that large amount of solid crystals can be classified by the crystal "**symmetry** (Answer of 1)." And large amount of **(i) solid, (ii) liquid, and (iii) gas can be classified by the theory of **Landau-Ginzburg theory of symmetry and symmetry-breaking (Answer of 2).**

Some of the solid states have phase transition between **the metal phase and the insulator phase,** called metal-insulator transition. Some of them can still be classified by the theory of Landau-Ginzburg theory of symmetry and symmetry-breaking,** but some can not.

```
 How about the (iv) plasma?
```

> 3. Can plasma be a gapped or gapless phase? Do **Landau-Ginzburg theory of symmetry and symmetry-breaking** classifies plasma or not? What are the symmetry and the symmetry breaking here? Are the classical E&M plasma and the quantum plasma the different phenomena? Are there something more exotic in plasma other than the Anderson-Higgs mechanism for the plasmon?

Comment: Your question is answered on Wikipedia already : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)#Definition A plasma can be seen as a gas or a liquid of charged particles, though the global charge of the complete system is zero. In short, ions in water is a plasma, electrons in a metal is a plasma, a gas of atoms when the electrons are free (atoms are said to be ionised in that case) is a plasma, ... almost everything is in fact a plasma if you look at it at a sufficient microscopic level. Landau symmetry argument does not apply to separate the *plasma phase* to the other phases.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to classifies the distinct "plasma" phases of matter?
> 2. What theory classifies the distinct "plasma" phases of matter?

These questions do not really make sense (unless I am misunderstanding your point).  A [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) is an ionized gas that exhibits a collective behavior similar to a fluid but is a kinetic gas.  There are not multiple *phases* of plasma.  There are collisional and collisionless plasmas though, i.e., those whose dynamics are governed by particle-particle collisions and those that aren't.

If you are asking what makes a plasma different from three standard phases of matter, then the answer is many things.  For instance, a plasma is governed by [instabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instability) and long-range interactions (i.e., [Coulomb collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision)).

> How about the (iv) plasma?

Plasmas do have extremely large [electrical conductivities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity), but they are not consistent with [Type-I superconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-I_superconductor).  In fact, plasmas are very different than both types of solid- and liquid-phase superconductors in that their dynamics are governed by electromagnetic fields.

> Can plasma be a gapped or gapless phase? Do Landau-Ginzburg theory of symmetry and symmetry-breaking classifies plasma or not?

I cannot say whether [Landau-Ginzburg theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) applies to [quark-gluon plasmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma) but it does not apply to electromagnetic plasmas like that in the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind).

> What are the symmetry and the symmetry breaking here?

I do not think this type of phenomena really matters for most electromagnetic plasmas.  It may be important near [pulsars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar) and/or [magnetars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar) where spin is very important and the particle [gyroradii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius) can be quantized.  However, for most situations a plasma can be treated classically as a [kinetic gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases).

> Are the classical E&M plasma and the quantum plasma the different phenomena?

Yes, electromagnetic plasmas are classical (except for the extreme cases I mentioned before) while quark-gluon plasmas are an entirely different beast mediated by different forces.

> Are there something more exotic in plasma other than the Anderson-Higgs mechanism for the plasmon?

I think [plasmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon) are primarily relevant to metals/solids.  I do not think the [Anderson-Higgs mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) is relevant to a classical kinetic gas.